# how to findall rows and get the total summation of amount for all rows in sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

when running this query.

```
 user.findAll({
        attributes: ['amount','currency','date'],
        where: {date: currentDate ,currency:currency},
      });
```

i got this response

```
[
    {
        "amount": "3000",
        "currency": "SDG",
        "date": "2019-12-30"
    },
    {
        "amount": "3000",
        "currency": "SDG",
        "date": "2019-12-30"
    }
]
```

**What I need like this**

```
{
"totalAmount":6000,
[
    {
        "amount": "3000",
        "currency": "SDG",
        "date": "2019-12-30"
    },
    {
        "amount": "3000",
        "currency": "SDG",
        "date": "2019-12-30"
    }
]
}
```

**I** **searched** a lot and **I did it by two queries** one for findall rows 
and the secound to sum the amount I'm looking for another solution any help or guide guys thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column in the attributes field as follows:

```
user.findAll({
        attributes: [
                     'amount',
                     'currency',
                     'date',
                     [sequelize.fn('SUM', sequelize.col('amount')), 'totalAmount']
        ],
        where: {date: currentDate ,currency:currency},
});
```

Comment: I tried this solution  it will got `{
        "amount": "3000",
        "currency": "SDG",
        "totalAmount": 3000
    }` the amount of row itself not all of them

Comment: I see, my bad. It's because you're missing the `GROUP BY` clause. In order to apply such aggregation inside a query, you need to group the result by a column. It's could be a problem to do such a thing. I guess that summing the result in the code after the query ends is a more intuitive and readable option.

Comment: the output above with `group by`

Answer (score 0):

I solved by map through all rows and sum the amount then attached to array.hope to find another solution more `sequelize`.

```
 let total = 0
 await Promise.all(
            rows.map(async(item)=>{
              total += Number(item.amount)
          })
          )
```